# Compile libcurl in MSYS2

Tags: c++, curl, makefile, libcurl, msys2

I have a problem with building libcurl in MSYS2 environment on Windows 10. I downloaded and extract the source then ran the following configure

`../configure --prefix=/f/Libraries/curl --with-ssl=/f/Libraries/OpenSSL --with-zlib=/f/Libraries/Zlib --with-libssh2=/f/Libraries/LibSSH2`

after its finished I give it a `make`

but fails with

```
[...]
  HUGE     tool_hugehelp.c
  CC       curl-tool_hugehelp.o
  CCLD     curl.exe
F:/msys32/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: curl-slist_wc.o:slist_wc.c:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_slist_append'
F:/msys32/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: curl-slist_wc.o:slist_wc.c:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_slist_free_all'
F:/msys32/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: curl-slist_wc.o:slist_wc.c:(.text+0x83): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_slist_free_all'
F:/msys32/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: curl-tool_cb_dbg.o:tool_cb_dbg.c:(.text+0x87): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_mfprintf'
[...]
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:930: curl.exe] Fehler 1
make[2]: Verzeichnis „/f/Libraries/curl-7.67.0/build/src“ wird verlassen
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1997: all-recursive] Fehler 1
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/f/Libraries/curl-7.67.0/build/src“ wird verlassen
make: *** [Makefile:945: all-recursive] Fehler 1
```

Ii can't figure out why libcurl does not find it's own library.

Comment: If IDE is VC++, use vcpkg for auto installation.

Comment: no IDE it's a MSYS shell, and i try to build a DLL